# Detect land type and adjust polygon area - Python

Tags: python, geopandas, mapbox

In my application, I have some code that draws a circle around a point on map. I am using Mapbox to render the map and a python function that takes a geopandas DataFrame, lat, longs, radius as arguments and creates a layer on the map with circle around the points.

```
import shapely.geometry
import utm
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, LineString
import shapely.speedups
shapely.speedups.enable()
import shapely.wkt
import rtree
import pygeos

def poi_poly(
             df,
             radius,
             poi,
             lon_col="Long",
             lat_col="Lat",
             include_radius_poly=False,
):

# generate a geopandas data frame of the POI
gdfpoi = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[shapely.geometry.Point(poi["Long"], poi["Lat"])],
    crs="EPSG:4326",
)

# extend point to radius defined (a polygon).  Use UTM so that distances work, then 
back to WSG84

gdfpoi = (
    gdfpoi.to_crs(gdfpoi.estimate_utm_crs())
    .geometry.buffer(radius)
    .to_crs("EPSG:4326")
)

# create a geopandas data frame of all the points / markers
if not df is None:
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
        geometry=df.loc[:, ["Long", "Lat"]]
        .dropna()
        .apply(
            lambda r: shapely.geometry.Point(r["Long"], r["Lat"]), axis=1
        )
        .values,
        crs="EPSG:4326",
    )
else:
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gdfpoi)

# create a polygon around the edges of the markers that are within POI polygon
return pd.concat(
    [
        gpd.GeoDataFrame(
            geometry=[
                gpd.sjoin(
                    gdf, gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gdfpoi), how="inner"
                ).unary_union.convex_hull
            ]
        ),
        gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gdfpoi if include_radius_poly else None),
    ]
)
```

How do I modify this to avoid any water area? I'd like to draw circle only on land. Like if there is significant body of water (say, 25% of area, shift the center of the radius) from the `poi` or something along those lines. I suppose this is fairly complex problem, however, wondering if there are any built-in functions / libraries in Python or Mapbox that we can leverage.